# Ya NO aparecen los mensajes en el terminal de VSCode

Tags: vscode, terminal

No puedo correr mi código en el terminal integrado de vscode, por un momento creí que eran por algunas extensiones que tal vez instalé, pero, aunque las desinstale no me aparecen los mensajes en la terminal, que puedo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías añadir más detalles a tu pregunta.
¿Puedes indicar tu sistema operativo y versión de Visual? 
¿Te han funcionado en algún momento y ha dejado de hacerlo?

Comment: @Orici tengo Windows 8.1 Pro (64 bits) y la versión de mi VSCode es 1.63.2. De hecho, si, estuvo funcionando bien, instalé algunas extensiones para cambiar los íconos y algunos temas para el editor, pero no creo que hayan afectado en nada al terminal.

Comment: A veces una nueva versión del editor rompe algo más o menos importante, te lo digo por experiencia. Otras veces me ha ocurrido que tenía un problema relacionado, creo, con alguna extensión. Normalmente las de deshabilitado todas e he ido activando hasta localizar cual era, también se arreglo con una actualización del propio editor. Es ir probando, quizás con la versión 1.63.1 te funcione. Te recomiendo guardar los ficheros de instalación de una o dos versiones inmediatamente anteriores por si hay problemas, a veces cuesta encontrarlas cuando tienes que desactualizar para seguir trabajando.

Comment: cambia de powershell a otra terminal y vas a ver como se arregla todo...

Comment: @Orici tendré que ir viendo extensión por extensión, gracias.

Comment: @gbianchi trataré de editar la ubicación en el settings.json, gracias.